# Are we fed up with the [spoon-feeding] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Since yesterday I’ve seen [spoon-feeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spoon-feeding) being used on a few questions <del>(5 as of now)</del>.

It was created by [torazaburo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo), its tag wiki says:

> Question where the author is requesting code to be written for him or her.

This is not really a technology, concept or topic about programming and seems off-topic. I don’t really see the point in telling an OP and other visitors that the question is bad in the form of a tag (that’s what voting is for).

So what is the point of this tag? Can it be burninated?

---

### Edit:

Well, that’s weird! Right after the question was posted, the tag magically disappeared from all questions. An example can be seen here in the [revisions of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34721949/revisions).

This question can be applied to any “meta tag” in general. If anyone can find a duplicate target of the question “how to deal with ‘meta tags’ on the main site” on this Meta site, let me know.

Comment: I don't see any questions in the list of posts tagged with it

Comment: Wow, a *rage* tag :-)

Comment: The problem with spoon-feeding someone is they may *still* complain "this porridge is too hot".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This issue has been taken care of.

[Meta tags are discouraged](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), and have been for a very long time. In the future, if you see this sort of behavior, flag the question with links to it happening and let us know about it.